# How to get data from ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get data from ajax call by cross domain.
Here is code

```
function GetMaxWULen() {
var x;
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'POST',
    jsonp : "callback",
    async : false,
    data : {
        Function : "GetMaxWULen",
        Authorization : Base64.encode(login + ":" + token),
        WuType : $("#ddlWUType").val()
    },
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossDomain : true,
    error : function(request, status, error) {
        alert('nie udało sie');
        alert(error);
    }
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log('done result');
    x = result;
    console.log(x);
});
console.log('function end');
console.log(x);}
```

At the end of the function, x variable is undefined but in done event value is correct.
Could anyone can help me or tell what is wrong in this code?

Comment: It's asyncronous, so that last line of code is executed before the request loads, therefore `x` doesn't have a value yet. It works in the `done` event because that waits for the request to load before executing the function.

Comment: above error: add `success:YourfunctionName()`, later then `YourfunctionName(response ){alert(response)}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Please use the search feature. This question has been asked hundreds of times.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your AJAX request is done asynchronously. It means the rest of your code won't wait your response be ready to continue.

If you need to use the data returned from AJAX outside your function, you might want to create a parameter to serve as a callback when the response is ready. For example:

```
function yourFunction(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        /* your options here */
    }).done(function(result) {
        /* do something with the result here */
        callback(result); // invokes the callback function passed as parameter
    });
}
```

And then call it:

```
yourFunction(function(result) {
    console.log('Result: ', result);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9duek/

Comment: but when I call function as You suggest and add return result to that call it still not work.

Comment: Edited the answer and added a working example at jsfiddle. If this is not working, you may have some problem in another part of your code.

Comment: You didn't get the idea. As your response is asynchronous, you  *can't* return it. Put the code that will manipulate your response inside the callback passed to `myFunction`

Answer (score -2):

try

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'POST',
    jsonp : "callback",
    async : false,
    data : {
        Function : "GetMaxWULen",
        Authorization : Base64.encode(login + ":" + token),
        WuType : $("#ddlWUType").val()
    },
    dataType : 'jsonp',
    crossDomain : true,
    error : function(request, status, error) {
        alert('nie udało sie');
        alert(error);
    }
}).success(function(result) {
    var datareturned = result.d;
    console.log('done' +  datareturned);
    x = datareturned;
    console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: Maybe if you'd explained what you'd done then people wouldn't have to ask.  He really only needs a simple example of why this async call was not acting in a synchronous manner, as that's obviously what his problem is.